# Can't call variable modules in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm trying to run an example program from a Python class I'm taking. The program is a load balancer simulation, that calls a random script name. The scripts are all identical and are named 'computer1.py', 'computer2.py' and 'computer3.py'. Here's relevant parts of the code:

```
import computer1
import computer2
import computer3

SERVERS = ['computer1', 'computer2', 'computer3']


server = get_server()

print(server.printName())

...
```

The get_server() function works correctly and returns either computer1, computer2 or computer3

The script bombs out at the next line when I try to call the printName() function from the returned server (printName does exist in all three of the computer files).

I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'printName'
```

The instructor was using Python 2.7 in the class so I'm guessing there is something different in 3.5 that is causing this to not work correctly.

NOTE: I don't believe this is a duplicate to the above question. I'm trying to dynamically call a different module using a variable name. If I do the following the script works properly:

print(computer1.printName())

However when I use a varaible for the call, ex:

print (server.printName())

I get the str error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your get_server returns a string literal out of your SERVERS array, not a module. Strings don't have a printName method. Did you perhaps mean:

```
SERVERS = [computer1, computer2, computer3]
```

So without the quotes...

Comment: the printName() method exists in each of the computerN modules:

Comment: def printName():
    print(str(__name__))

Comment: Ahh, I see it now! Thanks!